# How to find which element occurs the most in a python dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x

If you have a dictionary in python how would you find which element occurs in it the most amount of times. For example if you had the following dictionary, the name Bob occurs the most(3 times)(Once as a key and twice as a value). How would you find that name that occurs the most?
Also, I would prefer not to import anything (as I am a beginner)

```
dict = {'Mark': ['Paul', 'Bob', 'Carol', 'Leanne', 'Will'], 'Paul': ['Will', 'Zach'], 'Bob': ['Sarah', 'Don'], 'Tim': ['Bob', 'Carol']}
```

Comment: pls paste the code properly and your attempt at soln as well

Comment: Have you tried anything and did you run into some *specific* problem? This currently looks like you want us to write code for what looks like a homework question...

Comment: See this article for how to create a [mcve]

Comment: Not a homework question, I just made up an example to make the question make more sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a way to do this without imports. It defines a `check` function, iterates through `dic` once to generate a `dic_count`, then uses another for-loop to get the `max_count` and the `most_common_name`.

Sidenote: Never name variables or functions after built-in Python functions or objects. This is why I renamed `dict` to `dic`.

```py
dic = {'Mark': ['Paul', 'Bob', 'Carol', 'Leanne', 'Will'], 'Paul': ['Will', 'Zach'], 'Bob': ['Sarah', 'Don'], 'Tim': ['Bob', 'Carol']}
dic_count = {}

# Adds string to dic_count if it's not in,
# otherwise increments its count
def check(string):
    if string in dic_count:
        dic_count[string] += 1
    else:
        dic_count[string] = 1

for key, value in dic.items():
    # Calls the check function for both keys and values
    check(key)
    for name in value:
        check(name)


max_num = 0
most_common_name = ""
for key, value in dic_count.items():
    # If the count is greater than max_num,
    # updates both max_num and most_common_name
    if value > max_num:
        max_num = value
        most_common_name = key
        
print(most_common_name)
# Prints Bob
```

If you would like to get multiple names, change the last part to

```py
max_num = 0
most_common_names = ""
for key, value in dic_count.items():
    # If the count is greater than max_num,
    # updates both max_num and most_common_name
    if value > max_num:
        max_num = value
        most_common_names = key
    elif value == max_num:
        most_common_names += " " + key
        
print(most_common_names)
# Prints Bob Will after adding an extra
# 'Will' to the dictionary
```

Alternatively, if you would like to avoid defining a function, simply replace the top part with:

```py
for key, value in dic.items():
    # Adds string to dic_count if it's not in,
    # otherwise increments its count
    if key in dic_count:
        dic_count[key] += 1
    else:
        dic_count[key] = 1
    for name in value:
        if name in dic_count:
            dic_count[name] += 1
        else:
            dic_count[name] = 1
```

Comment: Awesome thanks. Is it possible to do this without defining a function and instead maybe creating an empty list and appending names as you count?

Comment: @Rickyboyy Of course, everywhere you see me use the function just replace it with its code, inserting the strings accordingly. This will make your code a lot longer, which is why I chose to define a function instead. I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I guess what you mean is how to find which element is the most common among all the lists that appear in your dictionary as values. If that's the case, the following should do the trick:

```
from collections import Counter
from itertools import chain

dict = {
    'Mark': ['Paul', 'Bob', 'Carol', 'Leanne', 'Will'], 
    'Paul': ['Will', 'Zach'], 
    'Bob': ['Sarah', 'Don'], 
    'Tim': ['Bob', 'Carol']
}

counter = Counter(chain.from_iterable(list(dict.values())))
counter.most_common()
[('Bob', 2), ('Carol', 2), ('Will', 2), ('Paul', 1), ('Leanne', 1), ('Zach', 1), ('Sarah', 1), ('Don', 1)]
```

---

If you also need to take keys into account, then:

```
counter = Counter(chain.from_iterable(list(dict.values()) + [dict.keys()]))
counter.most_common()
[('Bob', 3), ('Paul', 2), ('Carol', 2), ('Will', 2), ('Leanne', 1), ('Zach', 1), ('Sarah', 1), ('Don', 1), ('Mark', 1), ('Tim', 1)]
```

---

If you don't want to use external libraries:

```
l = list(dict.keys()) + sum(list(dict.values()), []) # flatten list of lists
max(l, key=l.count)
>>> 'Bob'
```

Comment: He wants the keys too

Comment: I want what appears most in the entire dictionary (so both as a key and a value). Also is there a way to do so without importing anything?

Comment: @GiorgosMyrianthous is it possible to do something similar without imports?

Comment: @Rickyboyy Quick explanation of what `flatten` means: Basically it just adds all the keys and all the values into a list, e.g. `{"a":["b","c"]}` flattened is `["a", "b", "c"]`.

Answer (score 1):

You can count the keys using a `Counter`, and update it with the count of the values.

You can then use the `most_common` method of the Counter to get the most common name:

```
from collections import Counter
from itertools import chain

d = {'Mark': ['Paul', 'Bob', 'Carol', 'Leanne', 'Will'], 'Paul': ['Will', 'Zach'], 'Bob': ['Sarah', 'Don'], 'Tim': ['Bob', 'Carol']}

count = Counter(d.keys())
count.update(chain.from_iterable(d.values()))
print(count.most_common(1))
# [('Bob', 3)]
print(count.most_common(1)[0][0])
# Bob
```

Comment: Is there any way to do this without importing?

Comment: Yes, of course, but that will require you to write more code than if you use the existing tools. Create a dict to store your counts, iterate on the dict's items, count the key, and count each name in the value. Then you'll have to find the key with the highest value among your counts.

Comment: Okay, I will look into that. I don't want to use imports yet

Comment: I'm still a little confused by this. Are you able to give me an example of the way to do it without imports?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a list with all items (keys + values) of the dict and use collections.Counter. d is your dictionary (dict that you used is not a proper name for Python as its already used fro built in structure)

```
from collections import Counter
l=[i for i in d.keys()]+[i for k in d.values() for i in k]

res=Counter(l)

>>> print(res)

Counter({'Bob': 3, 'Paul': 2, 'Carol': 2, 'Will': 2, 'Mark': 1, 'Tim': 1, 'Leanne': 1, 'Zach': 1, 'Sarah': 1, 'Don': 1})
```

Comment: Is this possible without any imports?

Answer (score 0):

By any chance are you looking for something like this

```
dic = {'Mark': ['Paul', 'Bob', 'Carol', 'Leanne', 'Will'], 'Paul': ['Will', 'Zach'], 'Bob': ['Sarah', 'Don'], 'Tim': ['Bob', 'Carol']}

#getting all the keys
keyslist=dic.keys()

#fetting all the values of dic as list
valuelist=list(dic.values())
#valuelist.append(keyslist)
test_list=[]
test_list.extend(list(keyslist))
for x in valuelist:
    test_list.extend(x)
    
#list with all elements from dict
print(test_list)
 

# get most frequent element 
max = 0
res = test_list[0] 
for i in test_list: 
    freq = test_list.count(i) 
    if freq > max: 
        max = freq 
        res = i 

# printing result 
print ("Most frequent element is : " + str(res)+ " Frequency :" +str(max))
```

Output:

```
Most frequent element is : Bob Frequency :3
```

I know this is not the best way ..if anybody have any suggestion to make please leave them in the comment i will edit my answer with those

Comment: This is good. However, when I tried applying this in a situation where there are 2 elements of equal value that are the most common it only displays one of them

Comment: @Rickyboyy My answer has a way to display multiple elements.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the comments in the code
Use chain to combine keys and values
Use defaultdict which is a special case of dict
where key is appended if not present

Code:

```
from itertools import chain
from collections import defaultdict

# do not use dict - no shadowing built-in dict
my_dict = {'Mark': ['Paul', 'Bob', 'Carol', 'Leanne', 'Will'], 'Paul': ['Will', 'Zach'], 'Bob': ['Sarah', 'Don'], 'Tim': ['Bob', 'Carol']}

#searching for one specific name occurence
name_to_search = 'Bob'
name_ctr = sum([1 for ele in chain(my_dict.keys(), *(my_dict.values())) if ele == name_to_search])
print(f'{name_to_search} occurs {name_ctr} times')

#searching for max occuring name in a dictionary
my_dict_name_ctr = defaultdict(int)
for name in chain(my_dict.keys(), *(my_dict.values())):
    my_dict_name_ctr[name] += 1
max_occuring_val = max(my_dict_name_ctr.values())    
most_occuring_names = [name for name,val in my_dict_name_ctr.items() if val == max_occuring_val]
print(most_occuring_names, 'occurs', max_occuring_val, 'times')
```

Output:

```
Bob occurs 3 times
['Bob'] occurs 3 times
```